# Which parts of Google Android platform are not open-source?

Tags: android, open-source

Which parts of Google Android platform are not open-source?

Comment: From Wikipedia: Source model: Free and open source software (3.0 is currently in closed development)

Comment: I see now that even Google can have closed-source apps like Google Maps. From a cursory search, it seems there aren't many phone companies doing closed modifications other than skins et al.

Comment: I am still not sure what is the difference between mods like CyanogenMod and http://android.git.kernel.org/. Anyone?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much everything is open source. The source is available at https://android.googlesource.com/

The Google apps are generally thought of to be part of the Android platform by consumers, but are not actually. They are not open source.

These apps include, 
GMAIL
Youtube
Google Maps
Marketplace
Maybe a few others I'm missing...

Manufacturer specific modifications such as Motorola Blur and Samsung Touchwiz are not open source.

Maybe hardware specific drivers are not open source.

Comment: Google Android Marketplace is one of those proprietary apps